# XNA 2D - How to set depth for depth buffer. Not using SpriteBatch

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, depth-buffer

How do I actually set the depth of something that I want to draw? I'm not using SpriteBatch.

My Sprite LoadContent looks like this:

```
public void LoadContent(ContentManager contentMananager)
    {
        myTexture = contentMananager.Load<Texture2D>("BarrelTrap");

        vertices[0] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };

        vertices[1] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X + myTexture.Width, Position.Y, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };

        vertices[2] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X + myTexture.Width, Position.Y + myTexture.Height, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };

        vertices[3] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X + myTexture.Width, Position.Y + myTexture.Height, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };

        vertices[4] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y + myTexture.Height, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };

        vertices[5] = new VertexPositionColorTexture()
        {
            TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0),
            Position = new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, 0),
            Color = Color.White
        };
    }
```

My Sprite draw code is like this:

```
public void Draw(GraphicsDevice graphics, BasicEffect effect)
    {
        effect.Texture = Texture;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {               
            pass.Apply();                
            graphics.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 2);
        }
    }
```

The draw code in the main game class looks like this:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        Sprite.Draw(GraphicsDevice, BasicEffect);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Which draws the sprite to the backbuffer just fine. I know how to create and set up a DepthStencilState, but I can't find how to actually set the depth of the sprite when I draw it. I'd like to be able to set the depth of the sprite when drawing. e.g.

```
Sprite.Depth = 0.5f;
```

Which would then ensure every pixel in the depth buffer for that sprite has a value of 0.5f, but I can't find out how to do it. It all works fine if I use a SpriteBatch. If I set the Z value for each vertex in the sprite it just disappears. It doesn't appear to be drawn at all. The BasicEffect and projection matrix I'm using look like this:

```
Matrix myProjection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, 1280, 720, 0, 0, 1);

myBasicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice)
{
    Projection = myProjection,
    TextureEnabled = true,
    VertexColorEnabled = true                
};
```

I just don't understand how the depth buffer gets written to in this situation. I realise that I can keep all the sprites in a list of some sort, manually sort them by depth and then draw them in order but I feel like there should be an easier solution. The SpriteBatch.SortMode works brilliantly but I can't replicate the effect.

I've searched all over the place and I can't find an explanation about how to actually *write values to the depth buffer*.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a SpriteBatch?

Comment: @Steven Shaders, basically. SpriteBatch doesn't play well with my shaders in the way I needed it to.